# Do regular functions separate points?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $K$ is a field, $V$ is a $K$-variety (finite type reduced separated $K$-scheme), and $p,q$ are $K$-points of $V$. Must there be an open subset $U$ of $V$ containing both $p$ and $q$ and a regular function $f$ defined on $U$ such that $f(p)$ and $f(q)$ are not equal? I am willing to suppose that $K$ is perfect but I doubt this is relevant.

This would give a nice proof of something I need. I have been unable to find anything useful in the literature, but I am very much not an algebraic geometer. I have asked a few algebraic geometers with no success. This question has been asked, but not answered, on stackexchange at least twice. Someone must know the answer to this.

Comment: This is clearly true if there is an open affine containing both $p$ and $q$, which always holds in many situations (e.g. if $V$ is quasi-projective).  Presumably a real algebraic geometer will give a more general answer, but I thought I'd point that out in case it suffices for what you are doing.

Comment: More generally, this is fine if $X$ embeds into a (possibly non-quasiprojective) toric variety. Hironaka's example of a nonprojective smooth proper threefold (see e.g. one of the appendices in Hartshorne's textbook) at least done carefully has the feature that there are two points without common affine neighborhood. I didn't check, but it is plausible that it gives a counterexample to your desired claim as well.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I do not think that Hironaka's example yields a counterexample since it admits a Zariski-locally projective morphism to a projective variety.

Comment: @AndyPutman Unfortunately that's not enough. I need to cover arbitrary varieties, which seems to add difficulty.

Comment: This reminds me of Weil restriction. Roughly speaking, the Weil restriction seems to be known to exist for varieties where every finite set of points is contained in an affine open subscheme. This condition of course implies yours. So maybe one can find a counterexample to your question by looking at examples where the Weil restriction does not exist?